# Calculating mb/s transfer speed for connection in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance-testing, bandwidth

I am using javascript to test the users transfer speed with files of a known size. However I feel the calculations are not returning speeds at which I would expect. 
Here is what I am using:

Time in milliseconds / 1000 = seconds

(file size in KB / seconds) * 8 = KB/s  [because of this article](http://www.attinternetservice.com/faqs/mbps-vs-mbps/)

KB/s  / 1024 = MB/s

Am I missing something?

Comment: The result of your calculation is megabits/second, which for my connection would be up to 72. What numbers are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: How are you timing it?

Comment: performance timing api, and my connection (accoring to speedtest.net is around 18mb) my stuff is showing around 4

Comment: The *8 is wrong, you already have KB. Although speedtest shows a certain speed there is no guarantee the Server you download from with js has that speed